# Mysql select ONLY one row FROM table WHERE columns having the same value occurs more than once

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id   user_id   animal
1      12       Cat
2      5        Lion
3      12      Snake
```

how do I select any one or the first one of user_id = 12. Please note: user_id 12 appears more than once in the table, I just need to select any one of them.

Comment: Do you also need "*Lion*" in your output?

Comment: how you want filter  ... the min ? .. the max  =?   .. you have two value related  to this user_id  .. so you must  choice

Comment: @Willem No I don't need the Cat or Lion in my output

Comment: What if there is nu `user_id = 12` in the table?

Comment: @scaisEdge I don't care how I filter.. I just need anyone of the two.. The other values don't matter.

Comment: @Willem Even if user_id occurs more than 100 times in the table.. I just need to select anyone of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say first or any, you can use limit.

```
select * from table where user_id=12 limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need one for each user and other and you don't matter the othres  row for the same user_id you can use

```
select * 
from  my_table 
where (id, user_id) in (select min(id), user_id 
                         from my_table
                          group by user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge for the answer.. But I think Krishnakumar answer is way simpler and easy to understand.